# Firebase 9: List subcollections of a document in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve data from customers generated from stripe/firebase integration using the new Firebase 9 (web client side, React.js)

Documents look like this:

```
/customers/Eaoxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx42/subscriptions/sub_1JylxxxxxxxxxxxxRd
```

The classic query doesn't "see" the subcollections:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const q = doc(db, "customers", currentUser.uid)
        const data = await getDoc(q)
        setCustomer(data.data());
    }
    fetchData()
}, [])
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no client-side API to list (sub)collections. To access documents, you'll need to know what (sub)collection they are in.

In the structure you show, the collection names are `customers` and `subscription`, both of which are known ahead of time and which you're expect to name in your code.

---

If you're looking to read subscriptions for a specific customer, you can access the `subscriptions` subcollection with:

```
const userSubscriptions = `collection(db, "customers", currentUser.uid, "subscriptions")`
```

---

If you want to read/query subscriptions across all users, [use a collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) which allows you to read from collections named `subscriptions` across the entire database.

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks Frank!